# Share my contact (other user) without username to other user, using telegram API (not bot API)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have an contact and know `tg_id` and phone of user. How to share this contact, using telegram API to other user?

[image]

Basically, I just want to copy the functionality in this “share this contact” screenshot, but I just can’t find the required method in the list of telegram API methods. Perhaps this API method exists, or can I share my contact in some other way? I know everything about this contact, but he doesn’t have a username. Also the link t.me/phone?phone is not suitable. I can DM to user, whom I want to share the contact

I have search all telegram API methods and can't find "share contact" method.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, you need to attempt simulating the situation through your own trials. If you do this, you will notice that if the person whose contact you want to share has restricted the visibility of their phone number in their privacy settings, you will not be able to perform a "share contact". Therefore, in the situation you describe, if the user does not have a username or phone number available, you will not be able to share this user's contact with others.

Comment: I know the person phone number and telegram id, and I can share this contact in app. But I just can`t find the api method, what perform 'share this contact'  button.